# What are these capacitors and resistors for?

Tags: brushless-dc-motor, motor-controller

I am studying a reference design (ST Microelectronics [STEVAL-ESC001V1](https://www.st.com/en/evaluation-tools/steval-esc001v1.html)) for an ESC used to drive a small BLDC motor.  On the output to the motor there are three 10nF capacitors in series
with three 1 Ohm resistors (one capacitor and one resistor per phase) going to DC common.

[image]

What purpose does this capacitor/resistor combination serve?  How are the values calculated?

Comment: Snubbers more than likely.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The RC network is called a "snubber" and it is used to prevent overshoot, undershoot, and ringing, caused by the FETs switching on at fast speed, and the parasitic inductances and capacitances of the circuit.

This prevents spikes of overvoltages from destroying components and reduces emissions of electromagnetic interference.

The part how to calculate them is more difficult.

One way is to determine the value experimentally, by measuring the ringing frequency without the snubber components, and adding known capacitances to see how they affect the ringing frequency. From this experiment the parasitic L and C values can be calculated and then these can be used to calculate R and C values needed to damp the ringing.

Another way is to just put something there that should be enough to damp it even if the values are not optimally calculated, and maybe try out a few values. As long as the signal gets slowed down enough but not too much for the application it should work.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback.  I’m going to do some homework on this.

Comment: @mike if this answer is satisfactory enough could you please accept it by clicking the tick under the points section so that the question does not remain open and popped up by Community modbot again after a couple of weeks? Thanks.

Comment: @RohatKılıç it's been proposed to accept an answer after a day, to increase the number of answers to a question. I'm not sure how well that compares to directly accepting though.

Comment: @Arsenal you're absolutely right. To be honest, while posting my comment above, I wasn't thinking about advising the OP to accept the answer right in the first time but now I re-read it and I admit that it looks like quite the opposite. My English... {facepalm}. What I meant was to remind them to accept the answer as soon as they got satisfied (not in the first time), instead of thanking. Because they may forget about the question after a satisfactory answer, or verifying it by practice. Then the question remains open and pops up after a couple of months. Just to prevent this... Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 5):

These parts optimize the ringing across the mosfets and help in passing EMC certification of the products.

The AN here guides you also how to design these values. JFYI.

https://assets.nexperia.com/documents/application-note/AN11160.pdf